# I can't get JavaScript to print user form data to the html document

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

Hey guys so I can't get JavaScript to print user form data to the html document. I have the html page set up with id's and the JavaScript should technically be printing to the document. Can anyone help me troubleshoot??? We've been learning JavaScript in classes however the online lectures suck and don't give me a hands on feel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS Project - Your Full Name</title>
    <style src="css/styles.css"></style>
</head>




<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="excel.html">Excel</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>






    <main>
        <form id="mainForm" name="mainform">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal Information </legend>

                <div>
                    First Name:
                    <input type="text" id="first-name" maxlength="50" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Last Name:
                    <input type="text" id="last-name" maxlength="50" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Email:
                    <input type="email" id="email" maxlength="50" name="email" placeholder="info@example.com">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Address:
                    <input type="text" id="address" maxlength="50" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                </div>

                <div>
                    City:
                    <input type="text" id="city" maxlength="50" name="city" placeholder="City">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Province:
                    <input type="text" id="province" maxlength="50" name="province" placeholder="Province">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Membership Options:
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="membership" checked value="p">Premium Membership
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="membership" value="s">Standard Membership
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="membership" value="b">Basic Membership
                </div>

                <div>
                    <!--<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="userInfo();">-->
                    <button type="submit" onclick="userInfo()">Submit</button>

                    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
                </div>
        </form>

        <span>

        </span>
    </main>


    <footer>
        <p>Canadian Business College - JavaScript Final Project - Your Full Name</p>
    </footer>
</body>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

IN SEPERATE JS DOCUMENT LINKED TO THE HTML:

```
function userInfo() {

  var myForm = document.mainform
  var firstName = myForm.firstName.value;


  if (firstName == null || firstName == "") {
  alert("Please enter your first name!");

  } 

    else {
      document.getElementByID("firstName").innerHTML = firstName;
      document.getElementByID("lastName").innerHTML = lastName;
      document.getElementByID("email").innerHTML = email;
      document.getElementByID("address").innerHTML = address;
      document.getElementByID("city").innerHTML = city;
      document.getElementByID("province").innerHTML = province;
    }

    else if (myForm.membership.value == "p") {
      document.getElementByID('firstName').innerHTML = "Full Name: " + firstName; + lastName;
      document.getElementByID('email').innerHTML = "Email: " + email;
      document.getElementByID('address').innerHTML = "Address: " + address; + city; + province;
      document.getElementByID('membership').innerHTML = "Membership: " + p;
    }

    else if (myForm.membership.value == "s") {
      document.getElementByID('firstName').innerHTML = "Full Name: " + firstName; + lastName;
      document.getElementByID('email').innerHTML = "Email: " + email;
      document.getElementByID('address').innerHTML = "Address: " + address; + city; + province;
      document.getElementByID('membership').innerHTML = "Membership: " + s;
    }

    else if (myForm.membership.value == "b") {
      document.getElementByID('firstName').innerHTML = "Full Name: " + firstName; + lastName;
      document.getElementByID('email').innerHTML = "Email: " + email;
      document.getElementByID('address').innerHTML = "Address: " + address; + city; + province;
      document.getElementByID('membership').innerHTML = "Membership: " + b;
    }

    onsubmit return 
}
```

Comment: "var myForm = document.mainform" surely you mean `var myForm = document.forms.mainform` note that this uses the name of the form and not the id, you don't need the id

Comment: And those variables are not declared inside this script `lastName, email, address...`

Comment: And where is this document that you want to be populated?

Comment: If that JavaScript code was supposed to update the HTML form, you are not using the ID's right. Half of the "getElementByID" references look for elements that are not there (misspelled slightly). EX: your getElementById wants "firstname" but the field ID is actually "first-name", and so on and so forth.